# Dynamic where condition LINQ

Tags: linq, select

I have a problem with my code. I don't know how I can insert in my selection all equals conditions of:

```
codicielementipartizione.sezione == el[i].ToString()
```

dynamically from

```
codicielementipartizione.sezione == el[1].ToString()
```

to

```
codicielementipartizione.sezione == el[el.count - 1].ToString()
```

Tn this code:

```
var selection = (from codicielementipartizione inlistacodici.cep
                 where codicielementipartizione.uno == 1 && 
                       codicielementipartizione.sezione == el[i].ToString() 
                 select codicielementipartizione).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the fixed part of the query which will be IQueryable. After that you can add your conditions as such.

Fixed part:

```
var query = from codicielementipartizione in listacodici.cep
            where codicielementipartizione.uno == 1;
```

Dynamic part:

```
foreach(var condition in el)
   query = query.Where(codicielementipartizione.sezione == el.ToString());
```

Query execution:

```
var result = query.Select().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this:

```
var selection = (from codicielementipartizione in listacodici.cep
                 where codicielementipartizione.uno == 1 
                    && el.Select(i => i.ToString()).Contains(codicielementipartizione.sezione)
                 select codicielementipartizione).ToList();
```